# Генерация новых объектов посредством случайных чисел (JS игра)

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, генерация-случайных-данных

Суть вопроса в том что при создании нового объекта - авто, их координаты накладываются друг на друга и генерятся кучками. Так вот, можно ли сделать так что бы перед генерацией происходила проверка при которой не происходило бы наложения.
Сами авто генерятся от выпадения случайного числа в диапазоне от 0 до 10000, при этом если число будет более 96065 генерится авто с случайными координатами по горизонтали от 10 до 356, 650 это координата высоты.

Пробовал прописывать изначально появление по полосам и по высоте, но тогда не будет рандома, искал в похожих проектах и не могу разобраться.

Спасибо большое хотя бы за подсказку.

Вот кусок кода в котором прописывается эта функция.

```
function Update() {
    roads[0].Update(roads[1]);
    roads[1].Update(roads[0]);

    if (RandomInteger(0, 10000) > 96065)//создание машины
    {
        objects.push(new Car("images/car2.png", RandomInteger(10, 356), 650 * -1, false));
    }

    if (RandomInteger(0, 10000) > 96065) //создание машины
    {
        objects.push(new Car("images/car2.png", RandomInteger(10, 356), 475 * -1, false));
    }

    if (RandomInteger(0, 100000) > 96065) //создание машины
    {
        objects.push(new Car("images/car2.png", RandomInteger(10, 356), 350 * -1, false));
    }

    if (RandomInteger(0, 10000) > 96065) //создание машины
    {
        objects.push(new Car("images/car2.png", RandomInteger(10, 356), 200 * -1, false));
    }

    if (RandomInteger(0, 10000) > 96065) //создание машины
    {
        objects.push(new Car("images/car2.png", RandomInteger(10, 356), 150 * -1, false));
    }

    player.Update();

    if (player.dead) {
        alert("Crash!");
        Stop();
    }

    var isDead = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i].Update();

        if (objects[i].dead) {
            isDead = true;
        }
    }

    if (isDead) {
        objects.shift();
    }

    var hit = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        hit = player.Collide(objects[i]);

        if (hit) {
            Stop();
            document.getElementById('sound').play();
            alert("Crash!");
            player.dead = true;
        }
    }

    Draw();
}
```

https://andrey1303110.github.io/JS_racing_game_v1.1/simulator.html

Ссылка на игру

https://github.com/Andrey1303110/JS_racing_game_v1.1

Ссылка на репу

[image: Скриншот игры]

Comment: Можно ещё меньше сделать диапазон но тогда машины станут реже появляться. Думал о том что сделать массив в котором прописать координаты появления, но это глупо.

Comment: Сама функция подбора чисел выглядит так:

Comment: function RandomInteger(min, max) {
 let rand = min - 1 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
 return Math.round(rand);
}

Comment: можно применить пару итераций алгоритма Ллойда https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm

Comment: или poisson disc sampling https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/

Comment: Ознакомился с poisson disc sampling - мне кажется это слишком сложный алгоритм для такой простой игры) может есть какие-то его более простые интерпретации чем такой сложный алгоритм)

Comment: ну можете проверять что следующая точка не находится слишком близко к уже добавленным, и выкидывайте если близко, но это медленный алгоритм =)

Comment: еще можно расставить по ячейкам и каждую случайно подвинуть не более чем на примерно треть размера ячейки